# MySQL - no lines returned on a very simple query

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with data entry and I really don't know where to start. I'm using MySQL 5.6.14 and I have a table with all the worlds known IP addresses in  columns include ipstart, ipEnd ip Country initial, ipCountry. I have around 81,000 entries  and when I conducted a very simple query via MySQL workbench:-

```
SELECT * FROM ipToCountry WHERE ipCountry = "Finalnd"
```

nothing came back. I tried Australia, and Slovenia but still nothing. When I simplified the query

```
Select *
```

everything came back and the countries I tried to query previously were indeed all listed, rows of them. I did a right click on one of the ipCountry values and selected open value in Editor and noticed that the cursor was on the next line down. I deleted all and then re-entered the name before selecting 'apply'
I ran the query

```
SELECT * FROM ipToCountry WHERE ipCountry = "Slovenia"
```

and hey prosto hte single line came back..

My question is how can I write a query to remove this carriage return from all 81,000 entries?

For reference - the data had been loaded via a csv and I checked the csv file and there were no additional carriage returns or extra lines in there... Please help (81,000 times)

Apparently I can't post the screen shot of the value in Editor but the entry looked like this
Slovenia
| (pip represents flashing cursor)

Comment: You can try WHERE ipCountry like '%Finland%'.

Comment: you should also post your create table statements charset collections can be case sensitive or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update all rows, replacing a new-line with an empty string:

```
UPDATE IpToCountry SET IpCountry = REPLACE(IpCountry, "
", "");
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not clear what that will leave me with... null values in my Table??

Comment: No, it will remove the new-line-character.

Answer (score 1):

To remove extra white space from a string you can use the trim() function.

```
  UPDATE ipToCountry SET ipCountry = trim(ipCountry);
```

Comment: Tried as you suggested but it did not work the addtional line is still there. I have also been doing some experimenting and it alwyas seems to hapen on the last column of the CSV. So, if you have a dummy column in your CSV, complete with dummy data, when you load it into MySQL it works fine. Of course you also have to add a dummy column in the table too so it can receive the data. then delete the dummy column when the import is complete. Sadly that still leaves me with the 81,216 rows I currently have in my DB